# Why is learning rate get constant result (not change)?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorboard, learning-rate

When I use object detection with Faster R-CNN I get this result in tensorboard:

[image]

Why do I get a constant result in my learning rate? What does that mean? Shouldn't my learning rate change each iteration?

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. Please have a read at the help pages [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Learning rate is a constant value unless you change it using step function or exponential function.